# BizTalk 2020 Http Authorization configuration ( Basic - Credentials + Certificate and OAuth2 )

Tags: authentication, biztalk, wcf-security, biztalk-2020

Im using BizTalk 2020 with all kinds of WCF Sendports.

At the moment i'm **improving the security of our end systems** which leads also to changes to our WCF-Sendports.

I would like to use OAuth2.0 or Basic Auhentication ( using Basic Credentials and Certificate ).
Within the Wcf-Sendports i only have the opportunity to **choose between** Basic Authentication using Credentials or Basic Authentication using Certificate:

[image: Wcf-Sendport Configuration]

As far as i know OAuth2.0 is only realizable adjusting the corresponding orchestration, or are there any default BizTalk settings offering this functionality?
Moreover is it possible to set up a combination of Basic Credentials and Certificate using default Wcf-Sendport Settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no default settings for OAuth2.0 in BizTalk. Also I've seen multiple different implementations of OAuth and they aren't very consistent to each other.

I've usually create a WCF EndPoint Behavior to get the credentials from SSO, call the OAuth URL with the credentials to get the token, and also cache and renew the token when it expires.   This way you can also do a messaging only solution, without needing an Orchestration.

You could also write a WCF EndPoint Behavior for other authentications.

Comment: So there is also no default setting for Wcf-Sendports to combine Basic Authentication using Credentials and Certificate, right?

Comment: @NDDev Correct.